# Create Java-Zip-Archive from existing OutputStream

Tags: java, apache-commons

Is it possible to create a Zip-Archive in Java if I do not want to write the resulting archive to disk but send it somewhere else?

The idea is that it might be a waste to create a file on disk when you want to send the Zip-Archive to a user via HTTP (e.g. from a Database-Blob or any other Data-Store).

I would like to create a

```
java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream
```

or a

```
apache.commons.ZipArchiveOutputStream
```

where the Feeder would be a ByteArrayOutputStream coming from my Subversion Repository

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely possible!

Create your Zip entry using the `putNextEntry` method on the `ZipOutputStream` then put the bytes into the file in the zip by calling `write` on the `ZipOutputStream`. For the parameter for that method, the `byte[]`, just extract them from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with its `toByteArray` method.

And the `ZipOutputStream` can be sent anywhere, as its constructor just takes an `OutputStream` so could be e.g. your HTTP response.

Comment: Alright, that worked! But how do I create Directories that actually contain the files themselves then? Right now I get all files, fine, but the directories are unpacked as files with zero-byte length in the root node, so no hierarchy at all :-(

Comment: ZIP files just contain a flat list of files. The file names, however, may contain path information. Just add a `ZipEntry` with a name such as `dir/file.txt`: that is `file.txt` within a directory `dir`.

Comment: Yes, by adding the absolute URL everything works a expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Something like that would work:

```
ZipOutputStream zs = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream) ;
ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(fileName);
zs.putNextEntry(e);
zs.write(...);
zs.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Input:** D:/in.xml

**Output:** D:/final.zip  (having 2 files 001zip.txt,002zip.txt)

**Code:**

```
package com.stackoverflow.filezip;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class fileZip {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:/in.xml");
OutputStream out=   new FileOutputStream("D:/final.zip");
ZipOutputStream zs = new ZipOutputStream(out);

            ZipEntry e1 = new ZipEntry("001zip.txt");
            ZipEntry e2 = new ZipEntry("002zip.txt");
            zs.putNextEntry(e1);
            zs.write("test content in file1".getBytes());
            zs.putNextEntry(e2);
            zs.write("test content in file2".getBytes());

            zs.close();
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                                       }
                       }
```