# ZipOutputStream leaving size=-1

Tags: java, io, zipoutputstream

I'm creating a zip file with `ZipOutputStream` using pretty standard code. For some reason when I read it back in as a `ZipInputStream` the `ZipEntry` has `size=-1`. The filename is stored correctly in the `ZipEntry`.

(When I make a zip file using my OS tools and then read it back in, the size is correct, so I assume the problem is with `ZipOutputStream` and not the `ZipInputStream`).

The context is a Spring MVC controller.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
// export zip file
String file = "/Users/me/Desktop/test.jpg";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file+".zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test.jpg"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
zos.closeEntry();
zos.close();
fis.close();

// import same file
String file2 = "/Users/me/Desktop/test.jpg.zip";
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis2);
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
// here: entry.getSize() = -1, zip.buf is an array of zeros... 
// but if I unzip the file on my OS I see that the original file has been zipped...
```

Comment: Are you zipping a zip file? `ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename+".zip");`

Comment: btw, a good note. Double-zip? =)

Comment: actually no. even with a different extension the problem remains

Comment: test.jpg.zip - O_O I dont really get what is that =) The problem could be with the pathes to the files. Try to debug and check that you are not transfering nulls. Also, as a parameter to the input stream use a File, but not a String. This will clarify whether you really have the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that entry.getSize() is simply unreliable: [Why ZipInputStream can't read the output of ZipOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169370/why-zipinputstream-cant-read-the-output-of-zipoutputstream)

The above post provides a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the next entry from the stream, like in this example:

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/corejava/zip/zipentry.html

When you set the size manually, it sure would give you a result, like you've shown "64527".
You better have a look at the zip examples. They will give you a clear image.
Also: [Create Java-Zip-Archive from existing OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016818/create-java-zip-archive-from-existing-outputstream)

Try something, like this:

```
        String inputFileName = "test.txt";
        String zipFileName = "compressed.zip";

        //Create input and output streams
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
        ZipOutputStream outStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));

        // Add a zip entry to the output stream
        outStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(inputFileName));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        //Each chunk of data read from the input stream 
        //is written to the output stream
        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        //Close zip entry and file streams
        outStream.closeEntry();

        outStream.close();
        inStream.close();
```

Comment: I already have 
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
in the code. Are you saying I need it again somewhere?

Comment: Not really. It is just a bit different code you need. Look up in th edit.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified it to the following. (The data isn't coming from a physical file but from a byte[]).
`code`
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename+".foo"));
zos.write(myBytes);
// debugging here: zos.current.entry.name is correct, but size=-1. myBytes.length however is 64527!
zos.closeEntry();
zos.close();

Comment: I updated the example code in the original question using your suggestions. The problem should be clearer now. Thanks